# How to verify that 'chained-composite-next-hop' knob is working on Juniper MX

Tags: juniper-mx

We have to enable 'chained-composite-next-hop' on Juniper MX series routes in our network. We have already enabled knob 'enhanced-ip' on MX series. Is the knob 'chained-composite-next-hop' enabled by default on Juniper MX series? Please confirm.

In case the 'chained-composite-next-hop' is enabled by default , then how we can verify it. What we have to check in the output of command 'show route table abc.inet.0'.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chained Composite Next Hops can look a *little* bit different depending on the use case, i.e. PE vs. P or BGP-LU vs. L3VPN vs. multicast. If this isn't what you're after, let me know and I can update the answer with more detail.

Let's assume it's an L3VPN PE.

First we need the next-hop ID of the destination we're checking. In this case it's 773.

```
jhead@R1> show route forwarding-table destination 192.168.1.1 table L3VPN
Routing table: L3VPN.inet
Internet:
Destination Type RtRef Next hop Type Index NhRef Netif
192.168.1.1/32 user 0 comp 773 6
```

Then we use that next-hop ID to look further into the next-hop structure. I have bypass LSPs set up, so we can see those here as well.

The "xe-0/2/0.0 weight of **0x1**" indicates that it is the primary path. Whereas the weight of "xe-4/0/0.0 weight **0x8001**" indicates that it is the bypass.

```
jhead@R1> show krt composite-next-hop index 773
Composite Nexthop:
  Index: 773 References: 5 
  Locks: 3 0x4c0de00
  VPN label: Push 299925
Indirect Nexthop:
Index: 1048575 Protocol next-hop address: 172.16.1.1
  RIB Table: bgp.l3vpn.0
  Policy Version: 0 References: 7
  Locks: 3 0x9c0cff0
  Flags: 0x2
  INH Session ID: 0x151
  INH Version ID: 0
  Ref RIB Table: unknown
        Next hop: 10.10.10.1 via xe-0/2/0.0 weight 0x1 
        Label-switched-path to-banff
        Label operation: Push 300014
        Label TTL action: prop-ttl
        Load balance label: Label 300016: None;
        Label element ptr: 0x4f8ee00
        Label parent element ptr: 0x0
        Label element references: 4
        Label element child references: 1
        Label element lsp id: 12
        Session Id: 0x0
        Next hop: 10.10.10.2 via xe-4/0/0.0 weight 0x8001 uflags Mark connection protection tlv
        Label-switched-path Bypass->172.16.1.1->172.16.1.2
        Label operation: Push 300448, Push 299872(top)
        Label TTL action: prop-ttl, prop-ttl(top)
        Load balance label: Label 300448: None; Label 299872: None;
        Label element ptr: 0x4f90580
        Label parent element ptr: 0x4f8ee00
        Label element references: 3
        Label element child references: 0
        Label element lsp id: 0
        Session Id: 0x0
      IGP FRR Interesting proto count : 7
      Chain IGP FRR Node Num : 1
         IGP Resolver node(hex) : 0x6914e68
         IGP Route handle(hex) : 0x4c89748 IGP rt_entry protocol : RSVP
         IGP Actual Route handle(hex) : 0x0 IGP Actual rt_entry protocol : Any
```

While we don't technically need everything above, it helps add color to the next-hop structure as the FPC has it.

We need to get into the shell of an FPC where that next-hop can terminate (we saw xe-0/2/0.0 above, so we use FPC0).

```
start shell pfe network fpc0

NPC0(R1 vty)# sh nhdb id 773 recursive
773(Compst, IPv4->MPLS, ifl:0:-, pfe-id:0, comp-fn:Chain)
    1048575(Indirect, IPv4, ifl:322:xe-0/2/0.0, pfe-id:1, i-ifl:0:-)
        1048574(Unilist, IPv4, ifl:0:-, pfe-id:1)
            632(Unicast, IPv4->MPLS, ifl:322:xe-0/2/0.0, pfe-id:1)
            771(Unicast, IPv4->MPLS, ifl:326:xe-4/0/0.0, pfe-id:16)
```

The important thing to see here is the structure starting with composite working toward a unilist which implies that multiple paths are available, but not necessarily used (remember, our unicast next-hop using xe-4/0/0.0 is an MPLS Bypass LSP, but since it's available here as a next-hop, switchover to it can happen almost instantly).

Lastly, bear in mind that this is an example of a single VRF with a single destination. As you add more VRFs/destinations that forward in the same direction, you'll start to see the composite nature more and more. Specifically, you'll have additional "Compst" entries pointing to the same Indirect next-hop (e.g. 1048575).

Answer (score 0):

The "chained-composite-next-hop" knob on Juniper MX series routers is not enabled by default. To verify whether it is enabled or not, you can check the output of the "show configuration routing-options" command. If the "chained-composite-next-hop" knob is enabled, it will be visible in the configuration under the [routing-options] hierarchy.

To enable the "chained-composite-next-hop" knob on Juniper MX series routers, you can use the following

```
cli
configure
set routing-options enhanced-ip
set routing-options chained-composite-next-hop
commit
exit
```